Underlining first reference with \vref from varioref
my question is similar to this post.
I want to reference using the \vref command using the varioref package. Furthermore I only want to underline the first reference, including the figure/table/equation and number but not the page reference e.g. Figure 1.1, page 3 (and the second reference is displayed as Figure 1.1, page 3.)
When I try to use the code from the post with vref it underlines the whole command, including the page reference e.g. Figure 1.1, page 3
I have also tried using the fancyref package to underline only the desired part but that resulted in the page reference displaying even when the reference is on the same page as the figure/table/equation.
Could someone provide some help or is there a different solution already?
Thanks!
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman,12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[german]{fancyref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{varioref}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

% Varioref Version
% Redefine \vref to underline the first reference
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\oldvref\vref%
  \renewcommand{\vref}[1]{%
    \ifcsname[v#1]\endcsname\relax%
      {\oldvref{#1}}%
    \else%
      {\underline{\oldvref{#1}}}%
      \expandafter\gdef\csname[v#1]\endcsname{1}% 
    \fi%
  }%
}

% Fancyref version
% Would need to add condition to only underline first reference as well
\frefformat{vario}{\fancyreffiglabelprefix}{%
\underline{\freffigname\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1},~Seite~#2%
}%

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\textbf{Abbildung Test} \par

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{test_image.png}
    \caption{Enter Caption}
    \label{fig:test_image}
\end{figure}

\textbf{Tabelle Test} \par

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Beispiel}
\label{tab:beispiel}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
Name & Name & Name \\ \midrule
1    & 2    & 3    \\
4    & 5    & 6    \\
7    & 8    & 9    \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\textbf{Fancyref Version - Page displayed even though it is on the same page} \\
first reference \fref{fig:test_image}\\
second reference \fref{fig:test_image}\\

\newpage

\textbf{Varioref Version} \\
first reference \vref{fig:test_image}\\
second reference \vref{fig:test_image}\\
first reference \vref{tab:beispiel}\\
second reference \vref{tab:beispiel}\\

\textbf{Fancyref Version} \\
first reference \fref{fig:test_image}\\
second reference \fref{fig:test_image}\\
first reference \fref{tab:beispiel}\\
second reference \fref{tab:beispiel}\\

\end{document}


Note that I got an error ! Package cleveref Error: cleveref must be loaded after varioref!. from your code, so I switched them around in my answer below. Make sure that you never ignore errors, that often leads to unexpected output.

The \vref command is implemented as \ref \vpageref, or when cleveref is loaded \cref \vpageref, where \vpageref prints one of the predefined texts if the label is on the same page, the previous page, the next page, or some page further away.
So you can pull the definition apart and apply \underline only on the \cref part.
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman,12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

% Varioref Version
% Redefine \vref to underline the first reference
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\oldvref\vref%
  \renewcommand{\vref}[1]{%
    \ifcsname[v#1]\endcsname\relax%
      {\oldvref{#1}}%
    \else%
      {\underline{\cref{#1}} \vpageref{#1}}%
      \expandafter\gdef\csname[v#1]\endcsname{1}% 
    \fi%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\textbf{Abbildung Test} \par

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Enter Caption}
    \label{fig:test_image}
\end{figure}

\textbf{Tabelle Test} \par

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Beispiel}
\label{tab:beispiel}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
Name & Name & Name \\ \midrule
1    & 2    & 3    \\
4    & 5    & 6    \\
7    & 8    & 9    \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\newpage

\textbf{Varioref Version} \\
first reference \vref{fig:test_image}\\
second reference \vref{fig:test_image}\\
first reference \vref{tab:beispiel}\\
second reference \vref{tab:beispiel}\\

\end{document}

Result:

Note that \cref \vpageref is safe because \vpageref will automatically remove the space before if the text is empty, for example when you set \def\reftextcurrent{} to print no extra text when the reference is on the same page.

Thank you so much for your help!
I have ran your code and the underline part works as intended.
Now my problem is that if I run the code without the \newpage, it displays "first reference Abbildung 1 auf dieser Seite" which was the same problem I encountered with the cleveref package. Because now we have defined the first vref command to always display the pageref aswell instead of checking if its the same page

@ToMa if you don't want the 'auf dieser Seite' then you can do \def\reftextcurrent{} as I mentioned in my answer.
